# How to programmatically show a DocumentGroup?

Tags: swift, swiftui, visionos, documentgroup

WindowGroups have ids, like this: `WindowGroup(id: "window_id")`, but DocumentGroups do not have an id. So opening like this does not work: `openWindow(id: "window_id")`.

The problem is that if the user dismisses the DocumentGroup, there is no way to reopen it again.

```
DocumentGroup(newDocument: { TestDocument() }) { file in // When it is dismissed, there is no way to bring it back.
    ContentView()
}

WindowGroup(id: "TestWindow") { // I can bring it back by opening it with its ID.
    TestWindowView()
}
.windowStyle(.plain)
```

Comment: So you want to not just open a document, but *reopen* a document that has previously been closed? That seems to be what the last sentence is implying.

Comment: Yes, either reopen the last document. Or just opening the document browser again.